# Angular 5 not able to use GreenSock animation file

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, gsap, scrollmagic

I have an Angular 5 app that I'm currently implementing scroll animations using the GreenSock.js library as well as ScrollMagic.js. One really important file for some reason it will not let me include in the project without errors called

```
scrollmagic/scrollmagic/minified/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js
```

When I attempt to import this file into the project I receive a list of errors-

```
./node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'TimelineMax' in '/Users/RyanIndustries8/Documents/Projects/WebSites/megakyle83/node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins'
 @ ./node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap.js 31:2-61
 @ ./src/app/home/home.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
errors @ client:167
onmessage @ socket.js:41
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs.js:170
(anonymous) @ sockjs.js:883
SockJS._transportMessage @ sockjs.js:881
EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs.js:86
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ sockjs.js:2957
wrapFn @ zone.js:1166
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
invokeTask @ zone.js:1517
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1543
client:167 

./node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'TweenMax' in '/Users/RyanIndustries8/Documents/Projects/WebSites/megakyle83/node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins'
     @ ./node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap.js 31:2-61
     @ ./src/app/home/home.component.ts
     @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
     @ ./src/main.ts
     @ multi ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts

Uncaught ReferenceError: tween is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.eval (home.component.ts:34)
    at l (scripts.bundle.js:2)
    at c (scripts.bundle.js:2)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:496)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:485)
    at timer (zone.js:2025)
```

This is what I have in my component.ts file-

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { TweenMax, TimelineMax, ScrollToPlugin } from 'gsap';
import * as ScrollMagic from 'ScrollMagic';
import 'scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap';
import 'scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/debug.addIndicators';

declare var $:any;
declare var TweenMax: any;
declare var TimelineMax: any;
declare var tween: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  // intro: object [];

  constructor(private router: Router) {

  }

public  ngOnInit() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      //Init Scroll Magic
      var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

      var scrollScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: 'a.leanArrow',
        triggerHook: "onLeave"
      })
      .setTween()
      .addIndicators({
        name: 'fade scene',
        colorTrigger: 'orange',
        colorStart: '#0000ff'
      })
      .addTo(controller);

      controller.scrollTo(function (newpos){
        TweenMax.to(window, 0.5, {scrollTo: {y: newpos}});
      });

      $(document).on("click", "a[href^='#']", function(e) {
        var id = $(this).attr("href");
        if($(id).length > 0) {
          e.preventDefault();

          controller.scrollTo(id);

          if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
            history.pushState(", document.title, id");
          }
        }
      });

    //loop through each img
    $('img').each(function() {
    //build scene
    var ourScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: this,
    triggerHook: 0.6
  })

  .setClassToggle(this, 'fade-in')
  .addIndicators({
    name: 'fade scene',
    colorTrigger: 'black',
    colorStart: '#ff0000'
  })
  .addTo(controller);
  });

    //Manage animatedMenu
    var animatedMenu = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: 'section',
    triggerHook: 0.1
  })

  .setClassToggle('#animatedMenu', 'fade-in')
  .addIndicators({
    name: 'menu scene',
    colorTrigger: 'purple',
    colorStart: '#00ff00'
  })
  .addTo(controller);
}
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue with the animation.gsap.js file in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game but I lately had the same problem and solutions I found either required ejecting app or didn't work.

This is what worked for me based on a few answers compiled together.

Assuming you have already installed gsap and scrollmagic node modules:

1. Install imports-loader and types/greensock

   ```
   npm install imports-loader @types/greensock --save
   ```
2. In tsconfig.app.json make sure that greensock is in the types array of compiler object:

   ```
   "types": [
     "node", "greensock"
   ]
   ```
3. In the modules where you need scrollmagic + gsap use following import declaration:

   ```
   import 'imports-loader?define=>false!scrollmagic/scrollmagic/minified/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js';
   import { TimelineMax} from 'gsap';
   import * as ScrollMagic from 'scrollmagic';
   ```